# IBDesignable in framework not working on embedded project

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, ibdesignable, swift-framework

I have created a framework which has a custom IBDesignable UIView. When I include only the framework in a project the IBInspectable properties are not show in the attribute inspector but I can use the view properties programatically.

I checked few posts on stack overflow with solution for similar issues and found this reply as useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/39999914/5548640. As I am developing the framework in swift I tried this solution by creating an extension instead of category (as there is no category in swift). This solution does not work as expected.

I do not want my framework users to see my code but should be able to use the @IBDesignable @IBInspectable features. Also I do not want the framework users to subclass to use the IBInspectable properties.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line of code in your pod file. Then using terminal use commands: pod install

[image]

```
 # Workaround for Cocoapods issue #7606
      post_install do |installer|
          installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
              config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
          end
      end
```